# Create vector of values with random increments

Tags: python, numpy, random

If we start with a vector between 0 and 1 with 10 increments

```
z = np.linspace(0,1,10)
```

how can I create a different version of this vector, where the increments are drawn according to a Poisson distribution with intensity lambda? Would I have to use something like cumsum?

Comment: What are your criteria? Fixed length? Fixed PTP?

Comment: Yeah, I can fix the length through normalizing I think. I don't know what PTP means here?

Comment: Peak to peak: max minus min: x[-1] - x[0]

Answer (score 2):

Cumulative sum is definitely the best solution for you. Good thing you answered that yourself.

```
dx = np.random.poisson(lam, size)
x = np.cumsum(dx)
```